# The text associated with this error code could not be found. No more Internet handles can be allocated

Tags: c#, uwp

I am getting this error while connecting websocket in my uwp app. This problem occurs when the internet reconnects and the application is in a suspended state. Internet speed is fine and it also connects after exiting the application but does not automatically reconnect after resuming app.

```
 await messageWebSocket.ConnectAsync(new Uri(URL));
```

On another system I get this error - The text associated with this error code could not be found. A connection with the server could not be established.

and if I run an API to check either internet is available or not it still give response.StatusCode=0
for example- https://s3.amazonaws.com

Comment: This reason might be that the previous **MessageWebsockect** connection hasn’t been disposed. My suggestion is that you could close the socket connection when your app is suspended, then reconnect it when your app resumes.

Comment: Yes. i am properly closing and disposing the WebSocket after internet disconnection and when the app gets suspended. It started giving me issues recently earlier it used to work. Nothing changed at code base so I wanted to know if something at the store side or Microsoft changed any event.

I am using NetworkHelper events to check if the network is available or not but sometimes it doesn't get fired that is the reason I am calling this API to ensure about internet connectivity

Comment: The NetworkHelper event might be stopped when your app in suspended status.  You could refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/support-your-app-with-background-tasks) to detect network status with background tasks.